# Any way to get timestamp on history command result without exporting any variable?

Tags: unix, history, unix-timestamp

I want to display timestamp on history command result, on googling I found that by using export HISTTIMEFORMAT=' %F %T ' , I can get the timestamp but in my environment exporting anything is not allowed.

Is there any alternate way to get history results with timestamp..?

Comment: I don't think you need to export it, it's a parameter to the current shell.

Comment: @Barmar : Thanks for replying ,
any alternate way to do the same..?

Comment: Just do `HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T'` without the `export`.